# TransactionFailureException in neo4j

Tags: maven, neo4j, ontology, turtle-rdf

I am doing a college project in which i have to import a ontology in turtle format in neo4j. I got a code on github and i tried executing it. It works with maven in eclipse. After running the code i am getting the following exception:

> org.neo4j.graphdb.TransactionFailureException: Timeout waiting for database to become available and allow new transactions. Waited 2m. 1 reasons for blocking: High Availability member state not ready.
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.coreapi.CoreAPIAvailabilityGuard.assertDatabaseAvailable(CoreAPIAvailabilityGuard.java:57)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.ClassicCoreSPI.beginTransaction(ClassicCoreSPI.java:172)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransactionInternal(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:575)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTransaction(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:380)
>       at org.neo4j.kernel.impl.factory.GraphDatabaseFacade.beginTx(GraphDatabaseFacade.java:368)
>       at org.neo4j.abcd.Executable.main(Executable.java:42)

here is the code:

```
package org.neo4j.abcd;

import java.io.BufferedInputStream;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.util.HashMap;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.GraphDatabaseService;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.Transaction;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.GraphDatabaseBuilder;
import org.neo4j.graphdb.factory.HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory;
import org.openrdf.rio.RDFParser;
import org.openrdf.rio.turtle.TurtleParser;

public class Executable {

/**
 * @param args
 * @throws Exception 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    if(args.length!=1){
        throw new Exception("Provide a file path as a parameter!");
    }
    Transaction tx = null;
    File file = new File(args[0]);
    File fp=new File("db.local");

    if(!file.canRead())
        throw new Exception("Can't read the file.");

    HashMap<String, String> settings = new HashMap<String, String>();
    settings.put("org.neo4j.server.database.mode", "HA");

    GraphDatabaseService db = new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory()
            .newEmbeddedDatabaseBuilder(fp).loadPropertiesFromFile("neo4j.properties").setConfig(settings)
            .newGraphDatabase();

    BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(file));

    RDFParser rdfParser = new TurtleParser();
    try{
         tx = db.beginTx();
    Neo4jHandler handler = new Neo4jHandler(db);


    rdfParser.setRDFHandler(handler);

    rdfParser.parse(bis, file.toURI().toString());

    System.out.println(handler.getCountedStatements());
    tx.success();
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        // Mark Transaction as failed
        if (tx != null)
        {
            tx.failure();
        }
        e.printStackTrace();

    }
    finally 
    {
        // Close Transaction
        if (tx != null)
        {
            tx.close();
        }
    }
}



}
```

I am completely new to neo4j and maven. 
Can someone please help with this.

Comment: Do you need to use HA mode for this? That typically indicates you want to run this clustered. If you don't need this, maybe try `new GraphDatabaseFactory()` instead of `new HighlyAvailableGraphDatabaseFactory()`.

Comment: What do you mean by " It works with maven in eclipse. After running the code i am getting the following exception". What does work means? At which point did it stop working?

Comment: Check out the RDF blog posts and the Cypher procedures here: https://jesusbarrasa.wordpress.com/2016/06/07/importing-rdf-data-into-neo4j

Comment: Thanks @InverseFalcon....your solution worked.